# Does IIFE always return undefined?

Tags: javascript

In the code snipped below, why the content of variable foo is undefined? I was expecting our IIFE statement return something!

```
var foo = (function (){
    var a=8;
    console.log("hi");
})();
```

Comment: It'll always return `undefined` if there's no `return` statement. Why exactly were you expecting the function call to return something?

Comment: I was expecting the result of IIFE being something. Just like for foo = function(){var a=0;}, we would get something for foo

Comment: By default, all functions, IIFEs included, return `undefined` in JavaScript unless a `return` statement is used.

Comment: If you do `foo = function(){var a=0;}` you are assigning the function to `foo` so of course you get something when you log `foo` (you get the function); but nothing was returned there and no function was called; it's just an ordinary assignment. If you then call the function and log the result you'll get `undefined` since that function also doesn't have a return statement ( `console.log( foo() ); // undefined` ). Another way to look at it is: `var foo = function () { ... }();` is just a more concise way of expressing  `var foo = function () { ... }; foo = foo();`

Comment: @Paulpro I wish you had turned it to an answer so people would upvote it and future reader would enjoy more canonical answer

Comment: I just intended it as a response to your comment to help clarify. I think Travis 's answer is good, based on your original question being "Does an IIFE always return undefined?". He showed an example of an IIFE that doesn't return `undefined`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function inside of your expression that you are invoking is not returning any values, so that is why `foo` is undefined. If it returned a value, then `foo` would contain that value.

```
var foo = (function(){
    var a = 8;
    console.log("hello");
    return "world";
})()
console.log(foo);//world
```

Comment: When I pass this to my console (chrome) it returns  `//world //undefined` Why does it return 'undefined' ? (Sorry, I am still learning the basics:))